# Flutter API how to display multiple data?

Tags: flutter, rest, fetch-api

This code below display one data only because i put 0 at line `final Album = Album.fromJson(data[0]);`. I intend to display multiple data but I don't know how to do that. Any idea?

BTW I got this code from https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data and modified it for my personal work.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('-----'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final Album = Album.fromJson(data[0]);
      return Album;
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want to return multiple Albums.
If that is the case, you can return a List of Albums and work with a foreach loop. This could look like this, for example:

```
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
List<Album> myAlbums = [];
final response =
await http.get(Uri.parse('-----'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  final data = List<dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
  data.forEach((element) { 
    myAlbums.add(Album.fromJson(element));
  });
  return myAlbums;
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a list-type Album.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
final response =
await http.get(Uri.parse('-----'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var listAlbum = data.map<Album>((json) => Album.fromJson(json)).toList();
    return listAlbum; 
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json must be like this=> [{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "quidem molestiae enim"
},
{
"userId": 2,
"id": 2,
"title": "quidem molestiae"
}]

Update your Album class like this.

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<Album> albumFromJson(String str) => List<Album>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Album.fromJson(x)));

class Album {
Album({
this.userId,
this.id,
this.title,});
  
int userId; int id;String title;

factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Album(
userId: json["userId"],
id: json["id"],
title: json["title"],);}
```

Then,
update your code

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
```

to

```
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
```

and

```
final Album = Album.fromJson(data[0]);
return Album;
```

to

```
final List<Album> AlbumList = albumFromJson(data);
return AlbumList;
```

Now you can get display multiple data (Data list);